# how to split single row to multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, split, subquery, mysql-workbench

I want to split each single row to two rows in mysql (I want to split num1 and num2 into two rows by comma). My data is like:

```
datetime1               count    num1    num2
2022-03-16 03:00:00     0        0,1     1,2
2022-03-16 04:00:00     0        0,1     1,2
```

and now I want data like this:

```
datetime1                count    num1 num2
2022-03-16 03:00:00      0        0    1
2022-03-16 03:00:00      0        0    2
2022-03-16 03:00:00      0        1    1
2022-03-16 03:00:00      0        1    2
2022-03-16 04:00:00      0        0    1
2022-03-16 04:00:00      0        0    2
2022-03-16 04:00:00      0        1    1
2022-03-16 04:00:00      0        1    2
```

Comment: You should not be storing data in this form in the first place. Your table is violating database normalization (NF1). If you are interested in the separate values, then store them separately. Your query result is what the original table should look like.

Comment: Is it always exactly two numbers in num1 and in num2? If not, you'll need a recursive query for this to generate the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a cross/inner join approach here with the help of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.datetime1,
    t1.count,
    t1.num1,
    t2.num2
FROM
(
    SELECT datetime1, count, SUBSTRING_INDEX(num1, ',', 1) AS num1
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datetime1, count, SUBSTRING_INDEX(num1, ',', -1)
    FROM yourTable
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT datetime1, count, SUBSTRING_INDEX(num2, ',', 1) AS num2
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datetime1, count, SUBSTRING_INDEX(num2, ',', -1)
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t2.datetime1 = t1.datetime1
ORDER BY
    t1.datetime1,
    t1.num1,
    t2.num2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Since version 8+ MySql supports LATERAL

```
select t.datetime1, t.count, n1.num1, n2.num2
from tbl t
cross join lateral (
   select SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.num1, ',', 1) AS num1
    UNION ALL
   select SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.num1, ',', -1)
   ) n1
cross join lateral (
   select SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.num2, ',', 1) AS num2
    UNION ALL
   select SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.num2, ',', -1)
   ) n2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=acb940590b6640a6473d2b0839b67518)