# Split a row into multiple rows on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, split

I have table like this

```
+-----+-----+
|name |total|
+-----+-----|
|a,d  | 17  |
|b,f  | 9   |
|a    | 8   |
+-----+-----+
```

if anyone could help me to solve this into

```
+-----+-----+
|name |total|
+-----+-----|
|a    | 17  |
|d    | 17  |
|b    | 9   |
|f    | 9   |
|a    | 8   |
+-----+-----+
```

NOTE: I used mysql here and probably have more than one comma(,) on the field 'name'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553551/how-to-split-single-row-to-multiple-rows-in-mysql might be helpful to you,and is each row have no more than one `,`?

Comment: Also, it might be easier to use a normalized table and not store the data like this

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? Does some maximal "values per name" amount exists?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/317088/set-into-multiple-rows/317090#317090